# how do i access my @me.com email account

Tags: ios, email, mobileme

I just set up a new @me.com email account through iOS5 beta and was wondering if there was a way to access through the web, or if anyone knew the imap server info. It looks like they are using some custom token system for auth on the phone.

Comment: Have you tried signing in to me.com?

Comment: @nathan yes, it just gives me the 'find my phone features'

Comment: Free MobileMe accounts, as you discovered, only give you access to find my iPhone. When icloud is officially rolled out this fall, you will get a free mail account, but until then you it is just a username, not an email address.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw the email address works, however, its only accessible on the phone

Answer (score 6):

At iCloud.com you can see your mail, calendar, etc :)

Comment: But (until you are on iOS5 or Lion) only "Find My iPhone" is available.

Answer (score 1):

Go to iCloud.com and enter you full username and password ensuring you include@me.com e.g.. username@me.com

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the iCloud.com, if you see findmyphone, just click the Cloud logo on the left of your "My Devices" and you should be directed to a main menu where you can access your mail calendar and all these